# How to divide mp3 stereo sound in two mono sound streams

Tags: objective-c, audio, mp3

Best all,

I am writing an app with **Xcode 5.1.1** and **objective-c**.
I have an .mp3 file with stereo sound. 
I want objective-c to take the file and divide in two mono sound streams.
If possible it would be really handy to put it in .aif format, but this is not necessary.

Comment: I don't have the authoritative answer but you're going to have to dive into AVFoundation API's to do this.  [Apple has some sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneMultichannelMixerTest/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009113-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) that takes two inputs and feeds it into one output (a multichannel mixer), and I suspect that if you do enough digging, you'll find how to do a multichannel unmixing.

Comment: Thanks, Do you know maybe a specific class which would be useful?